# Incrementing counter in a javascript iterator

Tags: javascript

I am trying to increment a counter on the js iterator.
Naturally, the index is re-initialized. Wondering what the standard practice is for keeping a counter in scope in js iterator without re-initializing the index variable.

One thought is to keep the index as a global property inside Customers, but somehow I feel that's not a good way to do it
Here is the code:

```js
console.log(`Custom Iterator`)

let store = {
  customers: [{
    id: 1,
    name: `Ali`,
    food: [1, 3],
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: `Usman`,
    food: [2]
  }],
  foods: [{
    id: 1,
    name: `Waffles`
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: `Fries`
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: `Pizza`
  }]
}

let Customers = {
  [Symbol.iterator]: () => {
    return {
      index: 0,
      next: () => {
       let index = 0;
       console.log(index);
        while (index <= store.customers.length) {
          return {
            value: store.customers[index],
            done: false
          }
          index++;
        }
        return {
          done: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

let iterator = Customers[Symbol.iterator]();
console.log(iterator.next().value);
console.log(iterator.next().value);
console.log(iterator.next().value);


/* for (let customer of Customers) {
  console.log(customer);
} */
```

Answer (score 0):

When the `[Symbol.iterator]` is called, you can create an index variable scoped just to while that iterator is running:

```js
console.log(`Custom Iterator`)

let store = {
  customers: [{
    id: 1,
    name: `Ali`,
    food: [1, 3],
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: `Usman`,
    food: [2]
  }],
  foods: [{
    id: 1,
    name: `Waffles`
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: `Fries`
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: `Pizza`
  }]
}

let Customers = {
  [Symbol.iterator]: () => {
    let index = 0;
    return {
      next: () => {
        const value = store.customers[index++];
        return {
          value: value,
          done: !value
        };
      }
    };
  }
}

let iterator = Customers[Symbol.iterator]();
console.log(iterator.next().value);
console.log(iterator.next().value);
console.log(iterator.next().value);


/* for (let customer of Customers) {
  console.log(customer);
} */
```

In this particular case, since you want to iterate over an array, you can also just yield that array instead - it's good to avoid messing with manual indicies when possible:

```js
console.log(`Custom Iterator`)

let store = {
  customers: [{
    id: 1,
    name: `Ali`,
    food: [1, 3],
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: `Usman`,
    food: [2]
  }],
  foods: [{
    id: 1,
    name: `Waffles`
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: `Fries`
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: `Pizza`
  }]
}

let Customers = {
  [Symbol.iterator]: function*() {
    yield* store.customers;
  }
}

let iterator = Customers[Symbol.iterator]();
console.log(iterator.next().value);
console.log(iterator.next().value);
console.log(iterator.next().value);


/* for (let customer of Customers) {
  console.log(customer);
} */
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how I am solving the problem atm

```js
let Customers = {
  index: 0,
  [Symbol.iterator]: () => {
    return {
      next: () => {
        while (Customers.index < store.customers.length) {
          let customer = store.customers[Customers.index++];
         customer.food  = store.foods.filter(food => customer.food.indexOf(food.id) > -1)
          // console.log(Array.isArray(customer.food) ? 'array' : object);
          return {  
            value: customer,
            done: false
          }
        }
        return {
          done: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```